# href is responding thought it is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

guys I have a situation here. Im trying to validate an input from user that if the input is `!= ""` it will do what inside the if and if its else it will do what inside the else. the validation is quite working except for one thing. though the condition is false it is still going inside the if condition and refreshing the the whole system by using this code `$(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');`

can you help me?

```
        $(document).ready(function (){
         var username ;
         var eadd;

$('#change_usrname_button').click(function (){
    username = $('#new_chnge_username').val();      

            if(username != "" ){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'account_setting_registrar_get.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data:'username='+username,
                        success: function (data){


                                   if(data.error == false){

                                    alert("your username is successfuly changed");

                                       $(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');
                                   }
                                   else{
                                    alert("update error");
                                 }
                       }  
                    });

                }

                else{
                   alert("please put the new username");
                 }


});



            $('#change_eadd_button').click(function (){


                eadd = $('#new_chnge_eadd').val();


                if(eadd != "" ){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'account_setting_registrar_get.php',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data:'emailadd='+eadd,
                            success: function (data){

                               if(data.error == false){

                                alert("your email address is successfuly changed");
                                $(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');
                               }

                               else{
                                alert("update error");
                               }

                             }
                        });
                 }

                 else{
                   alert("please put the new username");
                 }



        });

            });
```

Comment: Make sure you're sending json from php with `json_encode`. Try `$.parseJSON(data.error) === false`.

Comment: muthu- http://pastebin.com/RSrGYWNz

Comment: What does `data` return?

Comment: this is the php http://pastebin.com/wWFUiaD4 the data return is from the echo json_encode($return);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking your validation should be a little more thorough...

You are only checking for empty string, however you also don't want it to be valid if the username is `null` or `undefined` as well.

You're validation should be the following:

```
if (username) {
 // ajax
}
```

This will check the following:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a good point that c0deNinja mentionned but if this is not the answer to your question, don't mark it as so. That way you'll have more people looking at your question. Just saying.

Comment: i tried to put correct data.. and remove the 
alert("your username is successfuly changed");                                     $(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');
inside the if(data.error == false){}
but still the browser refresh and changed the username

Answer (score 0):

You should use `data.error=='false'` because the response you may getting is a string in json format.

Answer (score -1):

```
       $(document).ready(function (){
         var username ;
         var eadd;

$('#change_usrname_button').click(function (){
    username = $('#new_chnge_username').val();      

            if(username){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'account_setting_registrar_get.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data:'username='+username,
                        success: function (data){


                                   if(data.error == true){

                                    alert("your username is successfuly changed");

                                       $(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');
                                   }
                                   else{
                                    alert("update error");
                                 }
                       }  
                    });

                }

                else{
                   alert("please put the new username");
                 }


});



            $('#change_eadd_button').click(function (){


                eadd = $('#new_chnge_eadd').val();


                if(eadd){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'account_setting_registrar_get.php',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data:'emailadd='+eadd,
                            success: function (data){

                               if(data.error == true){

                                alert("your email address is successfuly changed");
                                $(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');
                               }

                               else{
                                alert("update error");
                               }

                             }
                        });
                 }

                 else{
                   alert("please put the new username");
                 }



        });

            });
```

You May try  this one sir..

Comment: i tried it but it still makes the browser refresh.  $(location).attr('href','account_setting_registrar.php');

Comment: because your username has value it does runs unders false so it just alert try to switch it

Comment: i tried not putting any value on it but still the browser refresh

Comment: i solve it.. it is happening due to the <form action="" method="post">